# How to query for nodes without children nodes with given name in JCR?

Tags: sql, jcr, jcr-sql2

I have the following node structure in the JCR:

```
firstNode (namespace:node1)
  |-- childNode1 (namespace:node2)
          |-- ...
  |-- childNode2 (namespace:node2)
          |-- ...
secondNode (namespace:node1)
  |-- childNode1 (namespace:node2)
          |-- ...
thirdNode (namespace:node1)
  |-- otherNode
```

How can I query this using `JCR-SQL2` so that I will retrieve all of the parent nodes that do not have children nodes named either `childNode1` or `childNode2`?

The end result in this case should be

```
/secondNode
/thirdNode
```